# When the matter is sub judice then does a person have the right to speak the truth in public?

Tags: india, indian-penal-code

I've filed a case against my husband including my in-laws for dowry torture, on the basis of which police arrested them before sunset in my presence. But my mother-in-law filed a false case that she was arrested after sunset and got Rs.50,000 as compensation.

In a public website I mentioned that they have lied and NHRC has awarded compensation to her without taking my statement, as I am the prime witness and the action was done on the basis of my case.

Now my question is, in a democratic country like India do I have the right to speak the truth when the matter is sub judice?

Answer (score 1):

Speaking about a matter that is [Sub judice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub_judice) in most Commonwealth jurisdictions can leave you open to contempt of court charges.

However, I question if the matter is actually sub judice if there is no case active with respect to the compensation. The matter appears to be irrelevant to *your* case.

Comment: No case is active with respect to the compensation. I've not spoken about any confidential document. I've just spoken the truth then how can it leave me open to contempt of court charges. In that website I've commented on a topic where this thing was mentioned that my mother-in-law was arrested after sunset and hence the NHRC awarded her Rs. 50,000 as compensation.